Foreign movie about husband that worked on an oil rig
I'm looking for a foregin movie about a husband that was not considered bright by the town's people. It didn't seem like the proper match. He had a brother who would have been a better match. And he/the husband was gone a lot and she started going to a doctor and they started an affair. I believe she may have been anemic?
It's set in a country where women were sub but not treated so bad. One scene they could not attend a funeral (maybe of an oil rigger?).
It was a tragic love story. Accent- yes, but I'm not good at those.

What is a "foreign movie"? We are not all Americans here. Help us out by listing the language you think it was in or the country you believe it was from.

I'm sorry about foreign was not clear. Maybe country was Ireland, Holland? It came out I think in the early 90s.

Feel free to [edit] those details into the question.

This sounds like Breaking the Waves
Oilman Jan is paralyzed in an accident. His wife, who prayed for his return, feels guilty; even more, when Jan urges her to have sex with another.
